# How to display a map of a map (C++)?

Tags: c++, stl

I made the following map to store data from a .log :

```
map<string,pair(int,map<string,int>)>.
```

I manage to store the data but not to retrieve it. What I do is:

```
cout<< "first string: "<< debut->first 
    << " pair (first int): "  << debut->second.first << endl;
```

(debut is a constant iterator of a map)

With that I get the first string and the int of the pair, but I don't know how to get the content of the map. I tried different syntaxes as `debut->second.second->first` or `debut->second.second.first` but of them work.

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: You’ll have a much easier time of things if you define a struct for your value, rather than using `pair` there.

Comment: That map is too overcomplicated. Try finding an alternative. Code like that becomes very hard to comprehend after a few months of writing it.

Comment: `debut->second.second` is a container, potentially storing multiple values. Which of them do you want to print? You likely need to iterate over the inner map the same way you iterate over the outer. You appear to be iterating over the outer map already, so you must know how.

Comment: `map<string,pair(int,map<string,int>)>` is invalid syntax, it needs to be `map<string,pair<int,map<string,int>>>` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't know how to get the content of the map.

You can print out the content of the innermost map as shown below([[DEMO]](https://onlinegdb.com/gEHt4hvPc)):

```
auto beg = debut->second.second.cbegin();
auto end = debut->second.second.cend();
while(beg!=end) //can also use for loop
{
    std::cout<<beg->first<<" ";
    std::cout<<beg->second<<std::endl;
    ++beg;
}
```

[Here](https://onlinegdb.com/gEHt4hvPc) is a more complete example for printing the all the content of the maps, just for demonstration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string,std::pair<int,std::map<std::string,int>>> m{ { "first", { 5, {{"a", 10}, {"b", 20}} }} ,
                                                                    { "second", { 6, {{"c", 100}, {"d", 200},{"e", 300} }}},
                                                                    { "third", { 7, {{"f", 400}} } }};
    
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //PRINTING THE CONTENT OF THE MAP
    
    auto debutBegin = m.cbegin(); //const iterator to beginning of outer map
    auto debutEnd = m.cend(); //const iterator to end of outer map
    
    
    while(debutBegin!=debutEnd)
    {
        auto beg = debutBegin->second.second.cbegin(); //const iterator to beginning of inner map
        auto end = debutBegin->second.second.cend();//const iterator to end of inner map
        std::cout<<debutBegin->first<<" ---- "<<debutBegin->second.first<<std::endl;
        while(beg!=end)
        {
            std::cout<<beg->first<<" ";
            std::cout<<beg->second<<std::endl;
            ++beg;
        }
        debutBegin++;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

##### Output

The output of the above program is:

```
first ---- 5
a 10
b 20
second ---- 6
c 100
d 200
e 300
third ---- 7
f 400
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to:

- split your printing into functions,
- print one map at a time, and
- use whatever number of variables/references you need to make your code clearer.

The code below is just an example that tries to follow that intent.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/EcP5b5hqb)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>  // pair

using inner_map_t = std::map<std::string, int>;
using outer_map_t = std::map<std::string, std::pair<int, inner_map_t>>;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const inner_map_t& m)
{
    os << "\t{\n";
    bool first_elem{true};
    for (auto& [key, value] : m)
    {
        auto& second_string{ key };
        auto& second_int{ value };
        os
            << "\t\t" << (first_elem ? "" : ", ") << "second string: " << second_string << ", "
            << "second int: " << second_int << "\n";
        first_elem = false;
    }
    os << "\t}\n";
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const outer_map_t& m)
{
    os << "{\n";
    bool first_elem{ true };
    for (auto& [key, value] : m)
    {
        auto& first_string{ key };
        auto& first_int{ value.first };
        auto& inner_map{ value.second };
        os
            << "\t" << (first_elem ? "" : ", ") << "first string: " << first_string << ", "
            << "first int: " << first_int << "\n"
            << inner_map;
        first_elem = false;
    }
    os << "}\n";
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    const outer_map_t m{
        { "one", { 1, {{"uno", 10}, {"cien", 100}} } },
        { "two", { 2, {{"dos", 20}} } },
        { "three", { 3, {{"tres", 30}} } }
    };

    std::cout << m << "\n";
}

// Outputs:
//
//   {
//      first string: one, first int: 1
//      {
//          second string: cien, second int: 100
//          , second string: uno, second int: 10
//      }
//      , first string: three, first int: 3
//      {
//          second string: tres, second int: 30
//      }
//      , first string: two, first int: 2
//      {
//          second string: dos, second int: 20
//      }
//   }
```

And another implementation, probably a bit neater.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/sMx8osqjo)

```cpp
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>  // pair

using inner_map_t = std::map<std::string, int>;
using pair_t = std::pair<int, inner_map_t>;
using outer_map_t = std::map<std::string, pair_t>;

template <typename T, typename U>
std::ostream& print_map(std::ostream& os, const std::map<T,U> m, size_t level_of_indent)
{
    std::string indent(4*level_of_indent, ' ');
    std::string next_indent(4*(level_of_indent + 1), ' ');

    os << "{\n";
    bool first{ true };
    for (auto& [key, value] : m)
    {
        os << (first ? "" : ",\n") << next_indent << "'" << key << "' : " << value;
        first = false;
    }
    os << "\n" << indent << "}";
    return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const inner_map_t& m) {
    return print_map(os, m, 1);
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const pair_t& p) {
    return os << "(" << p.first << ", " << p.second << ")";
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const outer_map_t& m) {
    return print_map(os, m, 0);
}

int main()
{
    const outer_map_t m{
        { "Alien", { 1, {{"speed", 90}, {"power", 90}} } },
        { "Jabba", { 2, {{"speed", 10}} } },
        { "T1000", { 3, {{"speed", 70}} } }
    };

    std::cout << m << "\n";
}

// Outputs:
//
//   {
//       'Alien' : (1, {
//           'power' : 90,
//           'speed' : 90
//       }),
//       'Jabba' : (2, {
//           'speed' : 10
//       }),
//       'T1000' : (3, {
//           'speed' : 70
//       })
//   }
```

Comment: Oh yes that's smart to split the two maps that makes it easier to manipulate! Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Very glad you liked it!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to iterate over the second map as well. Here's one way to do this:

```
map<string,pair<int,map<string,int>>> mp1;
map<string, int> mp2;

mp2["str2 inside mp1"] = 1;
mp1["str1 (key)"] = {2, mp2};


for(auto pair1 : mp1) {
    cout << "First string: " << pair1.first << "\n"; // str1 (key)
    cout << "First int: " << pair1.second.first << "\n"; // First int: 2
    
    for(auto pair2 : pair1.second.second) {
        cout << "Second string: " << pair2.first << "\n"; // Second string: str2 inside mp1
        cout << "Second int: " << pair2.second << "\n"; // Second int: 1
    }
}
```

However (as the comments suggest) this is a complicated approach, maybe you need to submit a new question explaining your usecase. My thought would be to seperate this into to seperate maps somehow.

Comment: Yess thank you it makes sense! And yes ofc I agree with you but my teacher wanted me to us this structure.

Comment: @NathanNowakowski You're most welcome :)